# SQL Server trigger to insert or update data into a separate table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 insert trigger that I'm writing that needs to conditionally insert or update existing rows in a separate table.

Each row inserted needs to be evaluated separately, and it's possible that multiple rows will be inserted in a single commit.

The table that the trigger exists on is only ever inserted into. There is a business requirement that for a given `AlarmId` that the initial insert will be used to set the information of the alarm, and that subsequent inserts of that `AlarmId` will be ignored unless that insert contains an `EndTime`, at which point the copied data will be updated to include the `EndTime`.

So, the relevant parts of the table would be:

```
ID | AlarmId | StartTime | EndTime
```

The (extremely simplified) trigger is below:

```
DECLARE @AlarmId AS INT
SET @AlarmId = SELECT AlarmId FROM inserted

IF (SELECT COUNT(AlarmId) FROM destinationTable WHERE AlarmId = @AlarmId) <= 0
BEGIN
    -- Handle insert here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Handle update here
END
```

We don't have a T-SQL developer here, so any help with how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. I believe that a cursor is the right way to go here, but am not certain, and am open to any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest mistake people make with triggers is assuming that the inserted and/or deleted collection only contains one row.  It's very likely for inserts, and almost a certainty for updates and deletes, that there can and will be multiple rows.

You definitely also want to avoid a cursor.  ESPECIALLY in a trigger.  Performance would be awful.

There's a simple set-based solution here, that would be something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE dt
   SET column=value, etc, etc
  FROM destinationTable dt
       INNER JOIN inserted i ON dt.AlarmId = i.AlarmId 

INSERT INTO destinationTable (your list of columns here)
    SELECT (list of columns)
      FROM inserted i
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM destinationTable WHERE AlarmId = i.AlarmId)
```

The INSERT only inserts where the data doesn't already exist... the UPDATE only updates rows that already exist.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I love how elegant this solution is (the same one posted by @JamesZ). It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I just identified one potential issue, but I believe that it can be fixed by moving the update to after the insert. The issue is that it's possible for an alarm to both start and end in the same insert (though it will not be in the same row). Is there any reason that I shouldn't do this?

Comment: The issue is that if the INSERT goes first, then the UPDATE will always update it... so you'd likely need to modify the update with a WHERE clause to make sure you're not always immediately updating rows you've just inserted (i.e. the update should only update rows that existed BEFORE the insert, right?).

Comment: I don't suppose that it's technically necessary for the row to have existed first (other than the update won't find a row to update). What's important is that if a row exists in the destination that the data is unchanged aside from the eventual addition of the EndTime.

Comment: Heh.  Only you know your requirements. If that's the case, there's no issue with flipping them around. Just test with some sample relevant data and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work as an insert trigger:

```
update d
set d.EndTime = i.EndTime
from 
  destinationTable d
  join inserted i on i.AlarmId = d.AlarmId
where
  i.EndTime is not NULL

insert into destinationTable (AlarmId,StartTime,EndTime)
select AlarmId, StartTime, EndTime 
from inserted i
where not exists (select 1 from destinationTable d
  where d.AlarmId = i.alarmId)
```

Didn't test this, but hopefully it works. If you also have updates to the table, then you'll have to handle that separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table dbo.t5   (
    id int identity,
    AlarmId  int,
    StartTime datetime, 
    EndTime datetime
   )
   ;
   go

   create table 
    dbo.watched   (alarmid int,
   endtime datetime)
   ;
   go


create trigger dbo.t1 on dbo.watched after insert as
begin

set nocount on

Declare @AlarmId AS INT

Declare @endtime datetime

Select @AlarmId =AlarmId FROM inserted

Select @endtime = endtime from inserted

IF  exists (SELECT  AlarmId FROM dbo.t5 WHERE AlarmId = @AlarmId)

/* we already have an entry for this alarmid */

    BEGIN
       if @endtime is not null 
/* is this the terminal entry? */ 

       begin
        select 'hello'
        update  dbo.t5 set EndTime = @endtime where AlarmId = @Alarmid
       end
    END
ELSE
    /* first time seeing this alarmid - create it */

    BEGIN
        insert into dbo.t5 (AlarmID,StartTime)
                        values (@AlarmId, GETDATE())
    END
end
; go

insert into dbo.watched (alarmid) values (1234)

insert into dbo.watched (alarmid) values (1234)

select * from dbo.t5

insert into dbo.watched (alarmid,endtime) 
           values (123, GETDATE())

select * from dbo.t5 where AlarmId=123
```

`dbo.t5` will be your tracking table. Had to add many blank lines so you can just cut and paste example. Like to use `exist` instead of `count(*)` but `count(*)` would also work. `Exist` is probably faster.